# Firebase hosting rewrites working locally but not in cloud - bug?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

This is my `firebase.json` file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "target": "md-viewer",
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
      "source": "/",
      "destination": "create_md.html"
    },
    {
      "source": "/view/*",
      "destination": "show_md.html"
    }]
  }
}
```

When running `firebase serve`, the rewrites work as expected. However, deploying and opening my app ("`appname.firebaseapp.com`") returns `404`. The deployment is succesful since I can customize the 404 page, and access my files by asking for them directly (`appname.firebaseapp.com/show_md.html`, for example).

What's wrong? Shouldn't `firebase serve` mirror online behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the "*destination*" key on the rewrite rule is a file, it has to be referenced with an absolute path:

```
    "rewrites": [
      {
      "source": "/",
      "destination": "/create_md.html"
    },
    {
      "source": "/view/**",
      "destination": "/show_md.html"
    }]
```

Also, the "*/view*" rewrite needs two asterisks, according to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#glob_pattern_matching).